# How to track redirect from sub-domain to root domain

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache

I'm looking for suggestion on how to start troubleshooting this issue: We have simple PHP/MYSQL app that worked flawlessly until last week. All of a sudden after logging in we are redirected to root domain (inventory.domain.com -> www.domain.com).

We can see that login was successful - main menu appears for a millisecond, before it's redirected.

I tried with different browsers and different machines.

It's on premise server without access from internet.

Is there way to track when and by what part of code is redirect initiated or any other idea how to proceed?

Comment: I’d start with browser dev tools, and look at what gets returned in the network panel. (Use “preserve log” or similar, so that it doesn’t clear after navigating elsewhere.) If you see content/page elements showing up for a split second, then it is likely a meta refresh or JavaScript, a server-side redirect seems less likely in that scenario.

Comment: To me this doesn't sound like a PHP-issue because you see the main menu for a moment. Php redirects wont load (a part of ) the page before they redirect. My best bet is a javascript issue.

Comment: I suppose "_and not a line of code changed - we did not perform any action on the server_" is true too?

Answer (score 0):

So.. this was a new one.
Apparently one of our ex employees put sort of a killswitch in app.
It was obfuscated in javascript and was checking an outside website if it should trigger or not. It had date and website triggers.

I used this for deobsucation:http://jsnice.org/

We are a law firm so it was really stupid thing to do.

Comment: I agree it was a stupid thing to do, but the fact that your company is a law firm shouldn't make any difference. Suggesting so is wrong on various levels.